# Getting <ctrl> + <backspace> to delete words in gnome-terminal and vim insert mode

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vim, gvim

It seems like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> deletes backwards one word at a time. That's great, but I'd really really like that this works with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> like most other apps.

What's the best way to do this? I'd need the change to affect gnome-terminal commands, command line vim and GUI vim.

Comment: In vim you can press D then, B and it will do the same thing. However, I too miss this feature in the terminal because you have to esc out and it doesn't work while operating in Insert mode. Awesome tip for CTRL + W.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [ for gnome-terminal ]

use [`stty`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) tool, good for visualzing what `bash` keyboard shortcuts are binded.

see your current bash keyboard shortcuts (my system output):

```
stty -a
```

my output:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 41; columns 76; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon
-ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0
ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

`werase` is responsbile for deleting an entire word.

running this will set `ctrl` + `backspace` to erase a word when pressed.

```
stty werase \^H
```

!note: this will set this option `only` to your current terminal/bash session. in order to apply this `permanently` you need to add previous command to `.bashrc` file at the end of it.

settings from .bashrc will be loaded every time you open gnome-terminal.

after this you are ready to go. enjoy.

### [ for vim and neovim ]

just paste this in `init.vim` or `vim.rc`:

```
" Map Ctrl-Backspace to delete the previous word in insert mode.
" solution: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-Backspace_to_delete_previous_word
noremap! <C-BS> <C-w>
noremap! <C-h> <C-w>
```

this will work in insert mode, ofc. thats the main point of defining this, for insert mode.

works in `neovim 0.5` and `lower` versions and also in `standard vim`.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks : )

Comment: my pleasure to help. i will add the part with vim when i will learn to edit that.

Answer (score 22):

**Note that** this will work in the terminal and the default emacs mode (which you are using if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> deletes the previous word for you). It will not work in bash's vi mode and will not affect vi/vim itself. This is, therefore, only a partial answer but the best this emacs user can offer.

---

This sort of thing is managed by the `readline` library whose behavior can be controlled via `~/.inputrc`. Edit (or create, if it doesn't exist) `~/.inputrc` and add this line:

```
"\C-H":"\C-W"
```

Now, open a new terminal and it should work.

#### Explanation

The `\C-H` is actually <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>. You can see keycodes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then, the key you are after. You will see that <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> returns `^H`.

Now, it *should* be possible to bind <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to the bash function that deletes the previous word (`backward-kill-word` or `unix-word-rubout`) by using `"\C-H": backward-kill-word`. However, I can't get that to work. It works perfectly well with different keys (`"\C-E": backward-kill-word`, for example, makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> delete the previous word) but for some reason, I can't get it to work with <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>.

So, as a workaround, we just map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which is already mapped to `backward-kill-word`. So, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, that will be translated to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which, in turn, will send `backward-kill-word`. I got the idea for this workaround from [this SU post](https://superuser.com/a/837764/151431).

Answer (score 10):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead: it works just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and doesn't require any configuration.

Comment: This is great, because I don't have to configure again when I use a new system

Comment: It's so annoying when switching programs to go from Ctrl+Backspace to Alt+Backspace though. It keeps messing me up.

Answer (score 4):

Up until very recently, gnome-terminal emitted the same code on <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, hence you cannot distinguish the two in your application.

This was fixed in vte-0.42, which is part of Gnome 3.18 released this autumn.

If you're using Wily, you can find updated packages in [Gnome3 Staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+packages).

Comment: can I get this to run in trusty without adding that huge PPA ?

Comment: Not without downloading, patching, compiling and installing the libvte 2.90 package that matches trusty. The patch is at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733246.

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machine. Just make sure you use tmux from master and nvim from linuxbrew and control+backspace works in bash and vim too!

(Get bash from linuxbrew too)