# How to delete words in the terminal with Ctrl-Backspace like in the rest of Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, delete, text

When I'm in a text in any program (browser, text editer, IDE) I can delete  3 words by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> 3 times.

This works perfectly in all programs, *except* for the terminal. In the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> simply deletes one letter, and I need <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete whole words.

Since I constantly switch between the terminal and other programs this is really annoying.

I tried the tip [I found here](https://askubuntu.com/a/701933/133190) (creating `~/.inputrc` containing `"\C-?":"\C-W"`) but that doesn't work for me. Now it deletes the whole word when I just press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> still just removes one letter.

Does anybody know how I can change this behaviour so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the word left of the cursor? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Press Ctrl + W ("W" for word).

Comment: @Jos - I know that one, and I could also use `Alt`+`backspace`, but I simply want it to be the same across all programs.

Answer (score 5):

This is not generally possible for bash by itself without help from the terminal emulator, because <kbd>Backspace</kbd> *is* usually the same keycode as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> (ASCII DEL) (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - ASCII backspace). (Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to verify.) That makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> essentially <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> ... which is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> or simply <kbd>Backspace</kbd> itself.*)

With some terminal emulators, there are settings which allow you to send custom keycodes for various key combinations. In particular, many have an option to customize what <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sends (to switch between ASCII DEL or backspace, usually). You might want to experiment with such options to see if the terminal emulator sends a different keycode for <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

---

* This also true for a number of special keys - <kbd>Enter</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, etc.

Comment: I'm using Tilix as an emulator.  In the quick keys setting I can't really find the option to set this specific thing though. Do you know if this is possible for Tilix, or do you otherwise know another terminal which can do this?

Comment: I use Terminator, which has the odd behaviour that, if I set Backspace to send Ctrl-H, then Backspace is Ctrl-H, but Ctrl-Backspace is Ctrl-?.  But looking at the docs, the screenshot in https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/manual/vteconfig/ shows a "Compatibility" tab in the Profiles section. That's where the option in Terminator is.

Comment: @muru Did you manage to do it in terminator?

Comment: @dimisjim I don't remember now, but if Terminator still behaves as in that comment (setting Backspace to Ctrl-H causes Ctrl-Backspace to be Ctrl-?), then try setting that option and then using `bind '"\C-?": shell-backward-kill-word'` (or `backward-kill-word`, depending on the exact behaviour you want)

Comment: @muru Actually setting backspace to ctrl-h does work but I still don't know how to replace alt-backspace with ctrl-backspace. I am on zsh so I am not sure if bind is relevant here. Actually this did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252464/3263374